# How to switch row value with column?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table which stores my data like this:

```
ID   Name   Value 
1    Tag1   20  
2    Tag2   30
3    Tag3   40
```

I wanna display the values for each tag like this:

```
ID  Tag1  Tag2  Tag3
1   20    30    40
```

I tried this for one column:

```
SELECT        
    ID
   ,Value AS Tag1
FROM
    dbo.TableLogger
WHERE
    (Name = 'Tag1')
```

How could I do for the rest of columns?

Comment: PIVOT!!!!!!! http://24.media.tumblr.com/6b6265de049e4b4b918ec66572b2d40f/tumblr_mh5fmkj58S1rycrkjo1_500.gif

Comment: Could you please give me a hint how could I do this? Thanks!

Comment: see below for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,
[Tag1], [Tag2], [Tag3]
FROM
(SELECT ID, Value,Name
    FROM TableLogger) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(Value)
FOR Name IN ([Tag1], [Tag2], [Tag3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Is there a way to show all the values? Not only the max(value).

Comment: Can you have multiple tag1's against an ID?

Comment: No. You're right. I got a little bit confused. It works. Many thanks!